# How to retrieve value from JSON using java

Tags: java, json

I like to get the value of `code` from below JSON but I am getting an error like below:-

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I am getting an error in below line of code

```
 Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
```

I have JSON object like below:-

```
{
    "products":
    {
        "productsApp13": {
            "code": "productsApp13",
            "name": "productsApp13",
            "attribute_set": "Apparel",
            "product_type": "product",
            "status": "active"
            }
    }
}
```

My code:-

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;


import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

 try {

                Object obj1 = parser.parse(new FileReader(path.directorypath));
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj1;

                String name = (String) jsonObject.get("products").toString();
                System.out.println("Testing Parse Value = "+name);
                request.payload = name;


                JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("code");
                Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
```

I know that `productsApp13` or `code` key is not an array while I am not able to identify any method to read this particular value.

Moreover, I also want to know that how can I modify this value for my payload

Comment: What is wrong with `((JSONObject) ((JSONObject ) jsonObject.get("products")).get("productsApp13")).get("code")`?

Comment: It's giving me an error .. it is not allowing .get again.

Comment: Please add the fully qualified name of your `JSONObject`, I used `wslite.json.JSONObject` and I was able to do this with casting.

Comment: I have added all my imports I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code worked for me:-

```
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("products");
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get("productsApp15");
        String firstName = (String) jsonObject2.get("code").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example works for me:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.JsonValue;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader("{\n" +
                "    \"products\":\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"productsApp13\": {\n" +
                "            \"code\": \"productsApp13\",\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"productsApp13\",\n" +
                "            \"attribute_set\": \"Apparel\",\n" +
                "            \"product_type\": \"product\",\n" +
                "            \"status\": \"active\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}"));
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();

        final JsonValue products = jsonObject.get("products");
        final JsonValue productsApp13 = ((JsonObject) products).get("productsApp13");
        final JsonValue code = ((JsonObject) productsApp13).get("code");

        System.out.println("code = " + code); // code = "productsApp13"
    }
}
```

To get access to `javax.json.*` I use the Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException .. Actually I am getting JSON object from file not from JSON reader . I have passed my file here .. but it throwing error        final JsonValue code = ((JsonObject) productsApp13).get("code"); .. it jumps to catch don't know why :(

Comment: I also checked by System.out.println("Checking Me ="+productsApp13);

Comment: value id coming null

Comment: I also tried    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("./src/test/com/testdata/ShubhamHTTPHelperTest.csv").getFile()));
           JsonReader reader = null;
           List<String> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
           
               reader = Json.createReader(is);
              final JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();

Comment: If you get the object from file, have you tried the last 4 operations of my code? Also, *please* use a debugger to check what kind of object you get when calling `jsonObject.get("products");`.

Comment: Yes I have tried and the same code I have sent you in my comment .. after using debugger the operation moves to catch in this 1st line itself :( -> InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("./src/test/com/testdata/ShubhamHTTPHelperTest.csv")‌​.getFile()));

Comment: can you please tell me how you create that JSON object with \n and + , is there any online generator present where I can pass my JSON and it will give me result like above

Comment: Just manually add line-breaks, I personally use IntelliJ as an IDE.

Comment: It will be hectic to use when the JSON structure is large

Answer (score 0):

try following hope it fix your problem

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getResponseAsString(getFilePath()));
        final JSONObject products = jsonObject.getJSONObject("products");

        final String name = products.toString();
        System.out.println("Testing Parse Value = " + name);

        final JSONObject productsApp13 = products.getJSONObject("productsApp13");

        final String code = productsApp13.getString("code");

        System.out.println("code value : " + code);

    }

    private static Path getFilePath() throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException {
        URL url = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("jsonFile.txt");
        if (url == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        return Paths.get(url.toURI());
    }

    private static String getResponseAsString(final Path filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath));
    }
}
```

Maven dependency to compile above

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20131018</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Reader org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl@3485923b
javax.json.JsonException: I/O error while parsing JSON

Comment: it appears to me, that you have invalid json file, can you validate that json string on http://jsonlint.com/